# Export Excel object in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am trying to export data to Excel from ASP.NET.  The downloaded file is created on the fly when a link is clicked.  The code that I use is something like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
```

I am not exporting from a grid.  I have a list of business objects that I want to loop through to export.

How do I have this file exported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be automating the Excel application in a server environment like ASP.NET.  This MSKB article should be enough to scare you away from it:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

OfficeWriter is a library for generating (and then streaming) Excel workbooks from ASP.NET that is intended for server use:

http://www.officewriter.com